# Disabling buttons based on input values doesn’t work on two forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, webflow

*First and foremost: I’m using Webflow, so the issue can be related to Webflow somehow.*

*Second, I’m still learning to code, so please keep in mind that I’m still a newbie.*

I’m using two same forms (different classes since, well, they are two separate elements) on a site because the one is static and another one is located in CMS (Collection List).

The thing is, they did work together before, but I did something, and… well, you know — I’ve tried to debunk what happened, but didn’t find a proper solution.

For some, very-very strange reason, only the latter works, e.g., if jobs-form-cms-button is the first, then it won’t work, but jobs-form-button will. And vice versa.

```
function checkform() {
    const formElements = document.forms["wf-form-jobs"].elements;
    let submitBtnActive = true;

    for (let inputEl = 0; inputEl < formElements.length; inputEl++) {
        if (formElements[inputEl].value.length == 0) submitBtnActive = false;
    }

    if (submitBtnActive) {
        document.getElementById("jobs-form-button").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("jobs-form-button").disabled = "disabled";
    }
};

function checkform() {
    const formElementsCMS = document.forms["wf-form-cms-jobs"].elements;
    let submitBtnActiveCMS = true;

    for (let inputEl = 0; inputEl < formElementsCMS.length; inputEl++) {
        if (formElementsCMS[inputEl].value.length == 0) submitBtnActiveCMS = false;
    }

    if (submitBtnActiveCMS) {
        document.getElementById("jobs-form-cms-button").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("jobs-form-cms-button").disabled = "disabled";
    }
};
```

I’ve renamed some vars and const because it didn’t work otherwise. Also, I did some stuff in order to make this code work with Webflow since I couldn’t add some attributes to the native Webflow elements, e.g., “Form Button” (“disabled” attribute was reserved for the system) — so I added the forms by myself via custom code element.

Comment: Both function names are exactly the same.  So only one is going to be used.  Change function name for one of the forms.

Comment: @T.Shah, I’ve tried, but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions have the exact same name, in JavaScript when both functions have the same name, the 2nd function will override the first function.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to change the name of the function, e.g., `function checkform()` to `function checkformCMS()`? If so, then it doesn‘t work.

Comment: @Georgy yes that is what I mean. Are you making sure that you're also changing the function names wherever you are calling the functions too?

Comment: I guess? I mean I did what I wrote above, not sure what else I should’ve done. Do you mind having a call?